# Sum the following series, where $e^y < 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sum the following series: $$ 1 + e^y + e^{2y} + e^{3y} + .. $$ where $e^y < 1$

So $e^y$ is less than one, that means $y$ is a negative number, which means that each term will be contributing less. But I find this to be a very vague question. Can you actually say that the sum is just $1$?

Comment: It's a geometric series.

Comment: @DanielFischer So?

Comment: So try remembering what a geometric series with ratio $q$ sums to. Then insert $q = e^y$.

Comment: Do you know the meaning of the assertion "The series [so and so] sums to [some value]"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a geometric series:
$$
\frac{1}{1-e^y} = 1+e^y+e^{2y}+\cdots
$$
which converges uniformly if $e^y<1$.

Comment: converges to what?

Comment: Converges to $1/(1-e^y)$ for any negative $y$.